# Can isolation joints between slab and wall be saw-cut after the pour?

Tags: concrete, masonry, driveway

Contractors poured a new concrete driveway slab up to existing concrete wall, concrete house foundation, and garage slab. Found out the day after the pour they did not install any isolation joints. The new slab is poured directly up to the wall, wall footing, foundation, foundation footing, and garage slab. Already one crack from the wall propagated onto the driveway slab. I'm expecting this to be a trend as the wall is new (one week before the driveway) and is probably going to settle and crack more.

Can isolation joints be cut into the edges of the driveway slab now to prevent further similar issues? Any other options than a full demo and pour?

The driveway pour is 4" thick with steel reinforcement (24" spacing on a grid pattern).

Site layout diagram below shows the new driveway which was poured between the wall, building foundation, and garage slab. I tried to make the control joint layout fairly accurate in the diagram.

The existing cracks (day 2 after pour) are shown in red.  The bottom crack goes through the masonry wall and into the new slab. It's wider at the top of the wall so appears to be a settling crack from the wall itself and probably did not start on the driveway. Either way, it's propagating through both objects. That's what got me looking for any kind of isolation joint between the driveway and anything else, and I realized there are *none*.

The upper crack in the diagram is a separate issue from this post. It started in the curb control joint but probably didn't follow into the slab because the joint angle into the curve is too shallow. That part likely would've been fine if they had dog-legged the joint into the curve.

[image]

Comment: I am NOT a concrete expert, but I would be having a conversation with the contractor if a brand new slab was cracking within 48 hours of the pour. That strikes me as _very_ wrong.

Comment: On the corner there should have been a gap yes but the other areas are questionable over 10’-12’ wide yes under I pour right up to the footing for sidewalks etc.

Comment: @Ed Beal thank you for the insight. The poured area between the main building and wall is ~9 ft and between the garage slab and wall is ~22 ft.